# Removing 4 pulled KBs from entire network quickly

Tags: windows

Had 4 Microsoft KBs go thru the entire network via WSUS and they are causing problems. How can I remove them all?

They are 2982791, 2970228, 2975719, 2975331.

SCCM 2012 R2 is used as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
wusa /uninstall /kb:2982791 /quiet /norestart 
wusa /uninstall /kb:2970228 /quiet /norestart
wusa /uninstall /kb:2975719 /quiet /norestart
wusa /uninstall /kb:2975331 /quiet /norestart
```

You can turn that into a .cmd file and then deploy it. ;)

Comment: Good answer... but rather than turning it into a cmd file and deploying that to all the network machines, it's pretty easy to use [SCCM to push that out to all the machines on the network](http://weikingteh.wordpress.com/2013/05/13/how-to-rollback-remove-a-patch-using-sccm-configmgr/).